# excel date/time format specification not converting text date/time to internal date format?

Tags: excel

I'm getting time stamps as text from a log and need to get excel to ingest this so it recognises it internally as a date/time format so that I can do math with it. It comes into the excel sheet as a copy paste operation.

The timestamps are in format: 2013-07-11 20:00 so I've formatted the cells where this goes as: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm.

For some reason however I still can't do math with those cells, e.g. subtracting one of those date/times from another results in #VALUE.

This in Office 2011 on Mac.

Any clues anyone?

Comment: This is probably still understood as a string and not as a date.
Have you tried the function =TIMEVALUE()?
Otherwise what happens when you copy and paste values in place?

Comment: that did the trick, thanks! Oddly though, the TIMEVALUE function manages to make sense of the time and date whether I have the custom format set or not... thus rendering the custom formatting option rather useless it would seem. But then again, this is Excel... :-) I also tried getting it to represent this in degrees internally: 33°20.500' by setting the format as [hh]°mm.000' needless to say that didn't work either.

Comment: @Balthasar Usually, correct dates stored as text can be converted by adding 0 or multiplying by 1 (or similar operation which doesn't change a number). You can then format the cells with dates as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have formatted them as a time stamp but is the text box truly a number, or is it pasted in as plain text? I have run into the problem before where Excel sees my numbers as text even after I have "Formatted" the cells otherwise. Try going into a cell and changing a value and seeing what format the cell is in.